# I can't output properly

Tags: perl, user-input

I'm trying to print a character from a file each time I get a char as input.
My problem is that it prints the whole line. I know it's a logic problem, I just can't figure out how to fix it.

```
use Term::ReadKey;
$inputFile = "input.txt";
open IN, $inputFile or die "I can't open the file :$ \n";

ReadMode("cbreak");
while (<IN>) {  
    $line = <IN>;
    $char = ReadKey();
    foreach $i (split //, $line) {          
        print "$i" if ($char == 0);         
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the `ReadKey` call into the `foreach` loop.

---

```
use strictures;
use autodie qw(:all);
use Term::ReadKey qw(ReadKey ReadMode);

my $inputFile = 'input.txt';
open my $in, '<', $inputFile;

ReadMode('cbreak');
while (my $line = <$in>) {
    foreach my $i (split //, $line) {
        my $char = ReadKey;
        print $i;
    }
}

END { ReadMode('restore') }
```

Comment: did that, and it doesn't print anything

Comment: Works for me. I'm adding a fully improved program.

Comment: thank you for this, I need it to print a char each time it gets a char from input. Now it prints the whole line after you type as many chars as the line's size

Comment: Works for me (Konsole 2.8.3, `$TERM=xterm`). Try again with adding to the program: `use IO::Handle qw(); STDOUT->autoflush(1);`

Comment: This is perfect, thank you very much. I'm sorry for the noob post, this is my first script:D

Answer (score 1):

Your original code has 3 problems:

- You only read the character once (outside the `for` loop)
- You read 1 line from input file when testing `while (<IN>) {` (LOSING that line!) and then another in `$line = <IN>;` - therefore, only read even #d lines in your logic
- `print "$i"` prints 1 line with no newline, therefore, you don't see characters separated

Answer (score -1):

My scrip reads all the files in a directory, puts then in a list, chooses a random file from the given list.
After that, each time it gets an input char from the user, it prints a char from the file.

```
#!C:\perl\perl\bin\perl

use Term::ReadKey qw(ReadKey ReadMode);
use autodie qw(:all);
use IO::Handle qw();
use Fatal qw( open );
STDOUT->autoflush(1);

my $directory = "codes";                                                                                #directory's name
opendir (DIR, $directory) or die "I can't open the directory $directory :$ \n";                         #open the dir
my @allFiles;                                                                                           #array of all the files
while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) {                                                                       #read each file from the directory
    next if ($file =~ m/^\./);                                                                          #exclude it if it starts with '.'
    push(@allFiles, $file);                                                                             #add file to the array
}
closedir(DIR);                                                                                          #close the input directory

my $filesNr = scalar(grep {defined $_} @allFiles);                                                      #get the size of the files array
my $randomNr = int(rand($filesNr));                                                                     #generate a random number in the given range (size of array)
$file = @allFiles[$randomNr];                                                                           #get the file at given index
open IN, $file or die "I can't open the file :$ \n";                                                    #read the given file

ReadMode('cbreak');                                                                                     #don't print the user's input           
while (my $line = <IN>) {                                                                               #read each line from file
    foreach my $i (split //, $line) {                                                                   #split the line in characters (including \n & \t)
        print "$i" if ReadKey();                                                                        #if keys are pressed, print the inexed char
    }
}
END { 
    ReadMode('restore')                                                                                 #deactivate 'cbreak' read mode
}
```